# Target class [ImportTransaksiR13_Controller] does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I was tried and still not find the problem.
I was re-check and not find any problem either on my route or controller
I hope anybody can help this

```
Target class [ImportTransaksiR13_Controller] does not exist.
```

This my route :

```
Route::get('/import_transaksi_r13', [ImportTransaksiR13_Controller::class, 'index'])->name('import_transaksi_r13')
```

```html
Route::get('/transaksiR13', 'ImportTransaksiR13_Controller@index');
Route::get('/transaksiR13/export_excel', 'ImportTransaksiR13_Controller@export_excel');
Route::post('/transaksiR13/import_excel', 'ImportTransaksiR13_Controller@import_excel');
```

And this is my controller

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\TransaksiR13;

use Session;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Imports\TransaksiR13Import;
use App\Exports\TransaksiR13Export;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ImportTransaksiR13_Controller extends Controller
{
       
    public function index()
    {
        $transaksi_r13 = Transaksi_r13::all();
        return view('import.transaksi_r13.index',['transaksi_r13'=>$transaksi_r13]);
    }
 
    public function export_excel()
    {
        return Excel::download(new TransaksiExportR13, 'Transaksi_R13.xlsx');
    }
}
      
    }

}
```

I'm using Laravel 8 and MySql for DB

Comment: can you check your route file that line import ya not use App\Http\Controllers\ImportTransaksiR13_Controller;

Comment: I was attach my controller on there

Comment: remove this controller and run check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have not import the `ImportTransaksiR13_Controller` class inside your route file. Can you please show all codes from your `routes.php`?

Comment: you are right I'm forget to add `use App\Http\Controllers\ImportTransaksiR13_Controller;`_Controller on my web.php
Thank you